# Java - regarding Android Studio alongside PyCharm

Tags: android-studio, java, linux-mint, oraclejdk

I'm running LinuxMint and developing in Android Studio while using PyCharm for a class so I can code in Python. I have openJDK7 installed and I'm currently using it for both Android Studio and PyCharm. Whenever I open Android Studio, though, it complains and says that I should use the Oracle JDK, not OpenJDK. Is there a way to install multiple versions of Java and update the environment variables so that Android Studio uses the Oracle JDK and PyCharm sticks with OpenJDK? Or would it make sense to use the Oracle JDK for both?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that that's just a warning, you can stick with OpenJDK and be totally fine. If you want to switch, switch all the way. Here's a guide on installing Oracle JDK on Linux Mint: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372